# A variant of Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: limits, measure-theory

Let $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers summing up to $1$.

Given a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{F})$, assume also the $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function, and let $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots)$ be a sequence of probability measures $\mathscr{F} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Then, is it true that
$$
\int_X f \mathrm{d}\left(\sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i\right)=\sum_{i\ge 1}a_i \left(\int_X f \mathrm{d}\mu_i\right)\,\,\,?
$$

Comment: What are your thoughts about?

Comment: I tried with limit and use the finite additivity of the integral, but I couldn't conclude.. moreover, it is not the first time that i find this kind of problem, that's why i posted it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers summing up to $1$ and $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots)$ be a sequence of probability measures $\mathscr{F} \to \mathbb{R}$, it is easy to see that $\sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i$ is in fact a (probability) measure.

Note that, for each $j$, $\mu_j \ll \sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i$. Since both measures are finite, we can apply Radon-Nikodym Theorem. So there is $h_j$ a measurable finite non-negative function such that 
$$ \int_X f \mathrm{d}\mu_j = \int_X f h_j \mathrm{d}\left(\sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i\right) \tag{1}$$
Since $\sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i \ll \sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i$, we can use Radon-Nikodym Theorem again (uniqueness a.e. of Radon-Nikodym derivative) to conclude that 
$$\sum_{i\ge 1} a_j h_j = 1 \textrm{ a.e. }$$
Then, from $(1)$, either using Dominated Convergnece Theorem (if $f$ is integrable) or Monotone Convergence Theorem (if $f$ is non-negative), we have
$$ \sum_{j\ge 1} a_j\int_X f \mathrm{d}\mu_j = \sum_{j\ge 1} a_j\int_X f h_j \mathrm{d}\left(\sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i\right) = \int_X f \left(\sum_{j\ge 1} a_j h_j\right) \mathrm{d}\left(\sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i\right) = \\=\int_X f  \mathrm{d}\left(\sum_{i\ge 1} a_i\mu_i\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to prove that. Ramiro's solution is beautiful, but, in fact, Radon-Nikodym theorem is not needed.

This alternative solution resembles (one possible) proof of the Dominated Convergence theorem and relies on absolute continuity of Lebesgue integral.

Denote $\sum_{i \ge 1} a_i \mu_i$ by $\mu$ and suppose $f$ is $\mu$-integrable. Also, in $\int_X$ letter $X$ is omitted.

Let us estimate
$$ \left| \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu - \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_i \right| = \left| \int f\,\mathrm{d} \!\left( \sum_{i \ge N+1} a_i \mu_i \right) \right| \le \int \lvert f \rvert \,\mathrm{d} \!\left( \sum_{i \ge N+1} a_i \mu_i \right) \tag{1}$$

Take $\varepsilon > 0$. By absolute continuity of the integral, there exists $\delta > 0$, s.t. $\int_A \lvert f \rvert \,\mathrm{d}\mu < \varepsilon$, whenever $\mu(A) < \delta$.

Sets $A_M =  \{ x\in X : \lvert f(x) \rvert > M \}$ decrease to $\varnothing$ as $M\rightarrow \infty$. So we can find $M$, s.t. $\mu(A_M) < \delta$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\int \lvert f \rvert \,\mathrm{d} \!\left( \sum_{i \ge N+1} a_i \mu_i \right) &= \int_{A_M} \lvert f \rvert \,\mathrm{d} \!\left( \sum_{i \ge N+1} a_i \mu_i \right) + \int_{X \setminus A_M} \lvert f \rvert \,\mathrm{d} \!\left( \sum_{i \ge N+1} a_i \mu_i \right) \le \\ &\le \int_{A_M} \lvert f \rvert \,\mathrm{d} \mu + M \!\left( \sum_{i \ge N+1} a_i \mu_i(X \setminus A_M) \right) < \varepsilon + M \sum_{i \ge N+1} a_i
\tag{2}
\end{align*}

Combining $(1)$ with $(2)$, we conclude that for sufficiently large $N$
$$
\left| \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_i - \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu \right| < 2\varepsilon,
$$
hence the series $\sum_{i \ge 1} a_i \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_i$ converges to $\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu$.

---

If $f$ is positive but its integral is infinite you may approximate $f$ by $f^M (x) = \max\{f(x), M\}$ and exchange summation with the limit as $M \rightarrow \infty$, using uniformness of the latter, to show that the series
$\sum_{i \ge 1} a_i \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_i$ diverges to infinity. Though I would call this «a variant of Monotone Convergence theorem».

Alternatively, you may begin with simple functions, as was suggested in other answers.

---

Note, that your claim is formally not true for all *measurable* functions. If the series $\sum_{i \ge 1} a_i \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_i$ converges, even absolutely, $\mu$-integrability does not follow: you may have $\int f \,\mathrm{d} \mu_i = 0$, but $a_i \int \lvert f \rvert \,\mathrm{d} \mu_i$ summing up to infinity. For instance, this is possible when $\mu_i$ are supported on disjoint sets, you may think of a counterexample on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. One minor but important detail to verify is that $\mu$ is indeed a measure. As will be shown below, once this is verified, the result immediately follows.

We begin by simplifying notation. Suppose that $\nu_1,\nu_2,\dots$ are measures on $(X,{\cal F})$. Define

$$ \nu: {\cal F}\to [0,\infty)$$

by letting

$$\nu(A) = \sum_{i} \nu_i(A).$$

We will show that $\nu$ is a measure on $(X,{\cal F})$.

Indeed, $\nu(\emptyset)=0$.

Now suppose that $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are disjoint elements of ${\cal F}$.

Then

$$ \nu(\cup A_j) = \sum_i \nu_i(\cup A_j) =\sum_i \lim_{n\to\infty} \nu_i (\cup_{j\le n}  A_j)=(*)$$

Therefore by the monotone convergence theorem,

$$ (*) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_i \nu_i (\cup_{j \le n} A_j)= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j \le n} \sum_i \nu_i(A_j)= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j\le n} \nu(A_j)=\sum_{j} \nu(A_j).$$

Now we can integrate with respect to $\nu$:

$$ \int_A d \nu = \nu (A) = \sum_{i} \nu_i(A) = \sum_i \int_A d \nu_i .$$

This clearly extends to any simple function:

$$ \int \phi d\nu  = \sum_i \int \phi d\nu_i,$$

Now for a nonnegative measurable function $f$, we have a sequence of nonnegative simple functions $\phi_n$ such that $\phi_n \nearrow f$. It the follows from monotone convergence that

$$ \int f d \nu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int \phi_n d \nu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_i \int \phi_n d \nu_i=(**)$$

Now apply monotone convergence to the righthand side to obtain

$$(**) = \sum_i \lim_{n\to\infty} \int \phi_n d \nu_i =\sum_i \int f d\nu_i.$$

Answer (score 0):

I like Ramiro's elegant answer, but this one is more basic. First, define $\mu:=\sum_ia_i\mu_i$. By definition, we have that $\int f\mathrm d\mu=\sum_ia_i\int f\mathrm d\mu_i$ when $f=\mathbf1_A$, and so this extends by linearity to simple functions. If $(f_n)$ is an increasing sequence of simple functions with $0\le f_n\uparrow f$ then $0\le a_i\int f_n\mathrm d\mu_i\uparrow a_i\int f\mathrm d\mu_i$ for each $i$ by the monotone convergence theorem, so by two more applications of the monotone convergence theorem
$$
\int f\ \mathrm d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\ \mathrm d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i\ge1}a_i\int f_n\ \mathrm d\mu_i=\sum_{i\ge1}a_i\int f\ \mathrm d\mu_i.
$$
For general $f\in L^1(\mu)$, split into positive and negative parts and we are done.